# Uninstalling multiple ports with the same prefix in Macports

Tags: macos, macports

I have installed a lot of Haskell related packages through MacPorts but due to problems related to update of some of those packages, I decided to move away Haskell package management from MacPorts.

I have 34 ports installed that start with the name `hs-` (like `hs-random` or `hs-primitive`) and I am trying to uninstall all those with a single command.

So far, I tried `sudo port uninstall hs-*` and `sudo port uninstall "hs-*"` but not success. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo port -v uninstall "hs-*"
```

That works for me; I'm on trunk base.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it with `port installed | grep "hs-*" | xargs sudo port uninstall`